# How is the phrase ”out of all relation" used differently in these two sentences?

Tags: meaning

1. The village enjoys a notability out of all relation to its size.
2. Investors have been selling out of all relation to what we know.

Comment: Why do you find the phrase used differently?

Comment: @Xanne I looked the phrase up and found the meaning was something like "incompatible." It makes sense in the first sentence, but I don't understand what the second one is trying to say.

Comment: The use of *incompatible* makes sense in both sentences. To paraphrase: (1) *The village enjoys a notability that's incompatible with its size.* (2) *Investors have been selling at a rate that incompatible with what we know.*

Comment: @JasonBassford I understand the paraphrased version. But where in the original sentence is "rate" indicated?

Comment: @Leon I infer *rate* from context. If several investors are selling something, then there have been multiple sales. *Rate* can describe either the sale prices or the number of sales in a period of time. The actual sentence doesn't refer to "what we know," but it almost certainly has something to do with the unexpected sale of stocks (or whatever the commodity is) against expectations based on one of those two things.